# sonarqube .sonar folder owned by root

Tags: sonarqube, root, sonarqube-scan

We are having difficulty with our Thoughtworks GO pipeline because we run sonar-scanner.bat on the CI pipeline, which creates a .sonar folder owned by root. The go pipeline runs under its own user and doesn't have permissions to delete the .sonar folder, so the second time the pipeline runs it crashes. How can we configure sonar so that it doesn't own the .sonar folder ?

Comment: I guess if _.sonar_ ends up owned by root, then the SonarQube Scanner was launched as root. If so, why not running the scanner with a regular user  instead ? It does not need root privileges.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas-SonarSourceTeam the scanner is being called via our go user which is not a root user.

Comment: "sonar-scanner.bat" => Windows? "folder owned by root" => Unix/Unix? There's something not clear in your question. Can you please clarify? In any case, everything that is created by a SonarQube scanner belongs to the user who triggers the execution of the analysis.